# Yield Return New breaking a line of code?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an ability where you dash through a wall, so to do this I'm dashing and then disabling the colliders for a layer which is going to have everything you can dash through on it. When I add the 'yield return new WaitForSeconds' function, you no longer dash.

I don't have a clue what to do...

```
using Player;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Phase_Through_Walls : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float cooldowntime = 1;
    public float nextPhaseTime = 0;
    public float currentDashTime = 0.0f;

    Movement moveScript;

    public float dashSpeed;
    public float dashTime;

    void Start()
    {
        moveScript = GetComponent< Movement>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Time.time > nextPhaseTime)
        {

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                StartCoroutine(Dash());
            }
        }
        


        IEnumerator Dash()
        {
            float startTime = Time.time;

            while(Time.time < startTime + dashTime)
            {
                moveScript.cc.Move(moveScript.moveDirection * dashSpeed * Time.deltaTime); //dashes
                Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(0, 8); //turns off colliders for a certain layer
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //waits a second
                Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(0, 8, false); //re enables the collider
                yield return null; //returns a null value
            }
        }




    }
}
```

Comment: does `moveScript.cc.Move` control your dashing?

Comment: yeah thats what controls my dashing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split up the responsibilities of your methods. Right now you have 1 method trying to accomplish 2 things and it is stepping on itself in the process. Once the `yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);` is called, control is not returned to the coroutine until that second is finished. So your "dashing" script has to wait for a second as well.

Instead make 2 separate coroutines. 1 of them to actually do the dash, and one for handling collisions. And call them at the same time as below. Also it looked like your missing a closing bracket for your `Update` method.

```
using Player;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Phase_Through_Walls : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float cooldowntime = 1;
    public float nextPhaseTime = 0;
    public float currentDashTime = 0.0f;

    Movement moveScript;

    public float dashSpeed;
    public float dashTime;

    void Start()
    {
        moveScript = GetComponent< Movement>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Time.time > nextPhaseTime)
        {

            if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
            {
                DoDash();
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    void DoDash()
    {
        Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(0, 8); //disable colliders BEFORE dashing initiates
        StartCoroutine(Dash());
        StartCoroutine(RestoreCollision());
    }

    IEnumerator Dash()
    {
        float startTime = Time.time;

        while(Time.time < startTime + dashTime)
        {
            moveScript.cc.Move(moveScript.moveDirection * dashSpeed * Time.deltaTime); //dashes
            yield return null; // waits for next frame
        }
    }

    IEnumerator RestoreCollision()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1); //waits a second
        Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision(0, 8, false); //re enables the collider
    }
}
```